# Unable to add a condition using a column from a secondary table on Kingswaysoft

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm-365, fetchxml, kingswaysoft

I'm trying to retrieve data using KingswaySoft, and I need to use columns from both the primary and secondary tables in my conditions. However, KingswaySoft does not support this functionality. I also attempted to use a nested query, but it did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to tweak the query little bit. [This blog](https://blog.thenetw.org/2019/07/10/conditional-groups-across-different-linked-entities-in-fetchxml/) will give you idea for that.

Basically, build the advanced find query, then download the fetchxml and tweak/test the downloaded fetchxml query in XrmToolBox - FetchXml builder.

This way you will get a working query to use in Kingswaysoft.